# Shield.IO license badges and Github. License badge not working

Tags: github, markup, badge, readme, shields.io

I have created an MIT license in Github for my project. It added a license file and now shows up as an MIT license.

I went to Shields.IO and it suggested links to my repo. One of which is the license badge.

I have added this to my read me using markup and all other badges work except the license badge.

I have also allowed shields requests to my Github by it requesting privilleges.

Is there anything else I have to do to get this to work?

I assumed Shields reads Github's license file inside the repo to get the type of license?

Comment: It would be useful to report a bug with an example here: https://github.com/badges/shields/issues

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue today in one of my repositories. At the end I fixed it by simply overriding the label of the license badge.

**Before**

[image: before]

**After**

[image]

This produces the following url:

https://img.shields.io/github/license/your-name/your-repository?label=license&style=for-the-badge

In my example I'm using the style `for-the-badge` which is optional of course.

Also make sure, that your repository contains a license file named `LICENSE.md` with the desired license.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue - it wasn't recognizing LICENSE or LICENSE.md with an MIT license in it.

For shields.io, I just overrode it for now with

```
[![License](https://img.shields.io/badge/license-MIT-green)](./LICENSE)
```

[image: License]

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue, but I found out that if you use **capital letters** sometimes it doesn't work. For example, instead of:

```
![GitHub](https://img.shields.io/github/license/user/MyRepository?style=flat-square)
```

You should use:

```
![GitHub](https://img.shields.io/github/license/user/myrepository?style=flat-square)
```